# Geometric sequences with trigonometry

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, geometric-series

For the following sum:

$\cos(2\theta) + \cos^2(2\theta) + \cos^3(2\theta) ...+ \cos^N(2\theta)$

Why is the range $\{0 < \theta <\frac{\pi}{2}\}$ for there to be a sum?

Comment: in general, an infinite geometric series only converges if $-1<r<1$ so you must avoid $\theta=0$ where $\cos(2\theta)=1$  and $\theta=\frac \pi 2$ where $\cos(2\theta)=-1$

Comment: There is always a sum for finite values of $N$ it is only in the limit as $N \to \infty$ that the restriction is required

Comment: Think about what the series looks like, as $N \to \infty$, if [1] $\theta = 0$ or [2] $\theta = \pi/2.$

Answer (score 3):

There is no restriction on the range for there to be a sum. For example if $\theta=\pi$ then the sum is $N$, or if $\theta=\pi/2$ then the sum is -1 or 0 depending on whether $N$ is odd or even. There isn't any value of $\theta$ where the sum is not defined.